# How can I add a random bool flag for the waypoints?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;
    public float rotSpeed;
    public bool random = false;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool goForward = true;
    private List<GameObject> curvedLinePoints = new List<GameObject>();
    private int numofposbetweenpoints;
    private bool getPositions = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        curvedLinePoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line Point").ToList();

        if (curvedLinePoints != null && curvedLinePoints.Count > 0)
        {
            transform.rotation = curvedLinePoints[1].transform.rotation;
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount]; 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);

        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(lineRenderer.positionCount > 0 && getPositions == false)
        {
            pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();
            numofposbetweenpoints = pos.Length / curvedLinePoints.Count;

            if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
            {
                transform.position = pos[index];
            }

            getPositions = true;
        }

        if (go == true && lineRenderer.positionCount > 0)
        {
            Move();

            Vector3 targetDirection = (curvedLinePoints[c].transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            curvedLinePoints[c].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, curvedLinePoints[c].transform.localRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed);
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;
    int c = 1;
    void Move()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;

            if (random)
            {
                newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, pos.Length)], distanceToTravel);
            }
            else
            {
                newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
            }

            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
            if (newPos == pos[index])
            {
                if (goForward)
                {
                    bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                    if (!atLastOne)
                    {
                        index++;
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;

                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index--; goForward = false; }
                }
                else
                {
                    bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                    if (!atFirstOne)
                    {
                        index--;

                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;
                            //transform.LookAt(curvedLinePoints[c].transform, Vector3.up);




                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index++; goForward = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        transform.position = newPos;      
    }
}
```

I tried this :

```
if (random)
            {
                newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, pos.Length)], distanceToTravel);
            }
            else
            {
                newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
            }
```

Before adding the random bool flag there was only the else line :

```
newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
```

The problem is when the flag random is true the transform is randomly moving on place because he is not completing each random position he keep changing positions each frame.

How can I make that he will pick up a random position move to that position and then will pick up a new random position ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to keep a field for the randomly selected index `randomIndex`, and set it at the start and when a point is reached:

```
int randomIndex;

// ...

void Start()
{
    // ...
    GetNewRandomIndex();
}

// ...

void GetNewRandomIndex()
{
    randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, pos.Length);
}

void Move()
{
    // ...
        if (newPos == pos[index])
        {
            GetNewRandomIndex();
    // ...
}
```